# python - selenium scraping rotten tomatoes for audience score

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape the audience score from rotten tomatoes. I was able to get reviews but not sure how use selenium to get the "audiencescore"

Source:

```
<score-board
audiencestate="upright"
audiencescore="96"
class="scoreboard"
rating="R"
skeleton="panel"
tomatometerstate="certified-fresh"
tomatometerscore="92"
data-qa="score-panel"
                >
<h1 slot="title" class="scoreboard__title" data-qa="score-panel-movie-title">Pulp Fiction</h1>
<p slot="info" class="scoreboard__info">1994, Crime/Drama, 2h 33m</p>
<a slot="critics-count" href="/m/pulp_fiction/reviews?intcmp=rt-scorecard_tomatometer-reviews" class="scoreboard__link scoreboard__link--tomatometer" data-qa="tomatometer-review-count">110 Reviews</a>
<a slot="audience-count" href="/m/pulp_fiction/reviews?type=user&amp;intcmp=rt-scorecard_audience-score-reviews" class="scoreboard__link scoreboard__link--audience" data-qa="audience-rating-count">250,000+ Ratings</a>
<div slot="sponsorship" id="tomatometer_sponsorship_ad"></div>
                </score-board>
```

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/pulp_fiction'
driver.get(url)

print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[slot=audience-count]').text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close enough. To extract the value of the *`audiencescore`* attribute i.e. the text ***96*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/pulp_fiction")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "score-board.scoreboard"))).get_attribute("audiencescore"))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/pulp_fiction")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//score-board[@class='scoreboard']"))).get_attribute("audiencescore"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  96
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

Answer (score 1):

The attribute value of `audiencescore` which is not any text nodes value that's why we can't invoke `.text` method to grab that value. So you have to call `get_attribute()` after selecting the right locator. The following expression is working.

```
print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#topSection score-board').get_attribute('audiencescore'))
```

#import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1- Get element score-board

2- Get audiencescore attribute from element

```
audiencescore = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('score-board').get_attribute('audiencescore')
```